# Differences between timeline code vs Document class code

Tags: actionscript-3, document-class

I'm trying to explain the differences between writing timeline code vs Document Class code, so far I have:

```
Timeline code:
- doesn't require a package and class declaration

Document Class code:
- requires a package and class declaration

Timeline code:
- starts working on the top-most line

Document Class Code:
- starts working from the constructor function

Timeline code:
- loops, conditionals and event listeners can be **outside** of a function

Document Class Code:
- loops, conditionals and event listeners must be **inside** a function
```

Are these correct, and is there anything else that would trip up people who are making the transition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time line code is old and not recommended way as it is not structured way to code. still,

**Timeline code:**
- you can not define access control modifier to functions or variables, by default, everything is public(as far as I know)

**Document Class Code:**
- you can define access control modifier

**Timeline code:**
- code runs every time control come in that frame

**Document Class Code:**
- document class being initialized only once

**Timeline code:**
- Variable's lifetime is only while control is in that frame

**Document Class Code:**
- Member variables are stay alive until application ends.

EDIT

**Timeline code:**
- Same as code written in ENTER_FRAME event in document class.

**Document Class Code:**
- Can achieve functionality of frame code using ENTER_FRAME event.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I am trying to teach someone who knows only timeline code to write code in the Document class, but it's been a long time so I've forgotten the differences...

Answer (score 1):

When writing code in a Class file, the person you're teaching may be tempted to write code that looks like this:

```
gotoAndStop(2);
movieclipOnFrame2_mc.stop(); // <-- uh oh...
```

This of course will trip them up because they are expecting that assets that exist on frame 2 will be available immediately after calling gotoAndStop(2), especially if they came from an AS2 background.  They'll need to learn ways to handle this quirky behavior.